# Имена массивов в си и арифметика указателей

Tags: c, gdb

В [этой](https://www.recurse.com/blog/5-learning-c-with-gdb) статье автор пытается рассказать о том, чем являются имена массивов в Си. Он показывает, что `a` и `&a` имеют одно и то же числовое значение, то разные типы. Имя `a` является указателем на первый элемент массива и имеет тип `int *`, а `&a` - то же самое, что `&a[0]`, и является указателем на массив из трех чисел.

Пример в конце статьи:

```
preserve do
  :escaped
    (gdb) print a + 1
    $10 = (int *) 0x7fff5fbff570
    (gdb) print &a + 1
    $11 = (int (*)[3]) 0x7fff5fbff578
```

И цитата автора: Note that adding `1` to `a` adds four to `a`’s address, whereas adding `1` to `&a` adds twelve!

1. Почему здесь написано, что к `&a` прибавляется 12, когда по логу видно, что прибавляется 8?
2. Почему прибавление единицы к `&a` инкрементирует значение гораздо больше, чем прибавление единицы к `a`? Что это за игра с типами такая?

Comment: А какой на вашей системе sizeof(int *) ?

Comment: У меня четыре байта. И у автора видно же, что не 12 прибавляется.

Comment: на самом деле `12` - точка отсчета `a[0]`, в примере вверху адрес для a[1] и так как инт - 4 байта, а разница между представленными адресами 8 - в итоге получаем 12

Comment: вот похожий вопрос: [How come an array's address is equal to its value in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу первого вопроса

> Почему здесь написано, что к &a прибавляется 12, когда по логу видно, что прибавляется 8?

Стоит обратить внимание, что в логе отображены **результаты** сложения, и между ними разница действительно 8 и это вводит в заблуждение. Но, чтобы узнать сколько прибавилось, нужно смотреть на начальный адрес

```
= preserve do
  :escaped
    (gdb) x/4xb a
    0x7fff5fbff56c: 0x01  0x00  0x00  0x00
    (gdb) x/4xb &a
    0x7fff5fbff56c: 0x01  0x00  0x00  0x00
```

И если смотреть разницу относительно него, то можно увидеть, что в первом случае она равно `4`, а во втором - `12` как и написано в статье.

Что касается второго вопроса

> Почему прибавление единицы к &a инкрементирует значение гораздо больше, чем прибавление единицы к a? Что это за игра с типами такая?

то возможно поможет перевод [аналогичного вопроса на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c)

Имя массива обычно вычисляется как адрес первого элемента, так что `array` и `&array` имеют одинаковое значение (но разные типы, `array+1` и `&array+1` не будут равны, если длина массива больше одного элемента).

Есть два исключения из этого правила: когда имя массива является операндом `sizeof` или унарного `&` (address-of) имя указывает на сам массив, поэтому `sizeof` возвращает размер всего массива, а не размер указателя.

Для массива определенного как `T array[size]`, `array` будет иметь тип `T *`. При инкрементировании его вы получите следующий элемент в массиве.

`&array` возвращает тот же адрес, но при этом тип указателя будет уже `T(*)[size]` - т.е. это указатель на *весь* массив, а не отдельный элемента. И когда вы увеличиваете этот указатель он добавляет размер всего массива, а не размер отдельного элемента.