# Имя массива — это указатель?

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Имя массива — это указатель в C? Если нет, то в чем разница между именем массива и переменной-указателем?

<sub>Перевод соответствующего [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957/8086115) с enSO.</sub>

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Имена массивов в си и арифметика указателей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/504472/186999)

Comment: глобальный или статический массив в ассемблер обычно транслируется, как метка, а указатель как переменная с адресом

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Массив — это массив, указатель — это указатель, но в большинстве случаев имя массива *преобразуется* в указатель<sup>1</sup>.

Это массив:

```
int a[7];
```

`a` содержит пространство для хранения семи целых чисел. Мы можем присвоить значение одному из них с помощью оператора присваивания, например, вот так:

```
a[3] = 9;
```

А это указатель:

```
int *p;
```

`p` не содержит никакого пространства для хранения целых чисел, но он `p` может *указывать* на такое пространство. Мы можем, например, установить указатель `p` таким образом, чтобы он указывал на один из элементов массива `a`. Для первого элемента это будет выглядеть так:

```
p = &a[0];
```

Это может быть немного неинтуитивно, но то же самое можно записать и вот так:

```
p = a;
```

Такая запись *не копирует* содержимое массива `a` в указатель `p` (что бы это ни значило). Вместо этого имя массива `a` преобразуется в указатель на его первый элемент. Так что это присваивание делает все то же самое, что и предыдущее.

Теперь мы можем использовать указатель `p` точно так же как и массив:

```
p[3] = 17;
```

Это работает, потому что оператор индексации массива в C определен в терминах  указателей. Выражение `x[y]` означает: начни с указателя `x`, пройди `y` шагов вперед и возьми то, что лежит на этом месте. Используя арифметику указателей, мы можем записать `x[y]` как `*(x + y)`<sup>2</sup>.

Чтобы это работало для обычного массива, такого как `a` например, имя `a` в выражении `a[3]` должно быть сначала преобразовано в указатель (на первый элемент в массиве `a`). Затем мы делаем три шага вперед и берем то, что лежит на этом месте. Другими словами, берем элемент массива под номером 3 (который является четвертым элементом в массиве, так как номер первого элемента — 0).

Резюмируя, имена массивов в программах на C в большинстве случаев преобразуются в указатели. Одно из исключений — это использование имени массива в операторе `sizeof`. Если бы `a` преобразовывалось в указатель в данном случае, то выражение `sizeof a` дало бы нам размер указателя, а не реальный размер массива, что было бы весьма бесполезно, так что в данном случае `a` означает сам массив.

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>Это сообщение является переводом [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641963/8086115) пользователя Thomas Padron-McCarthy.</sub>

<sub><sup>1</sup> Более строго это определено стандартом: «*Выражение типа „массив типа“ преобразуется в выражение с типом «указатель на тип», который указывает на первый элемент объекта массива и не является lvalue. Исключениям являются случаи, когда выражение „массив типа“ является операндом оператора `sizeof`, или операндом унарного оператора `&` или это строковой литерал, используемый для инициализации массива. Если объект массива имеет регистровый класс хранения, поведение не определено*» — ISO/IEC 9899:2011 раздел 6.3.2.1 (примечание переводчика).</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> «*Определение оператора индексации `[]` следующее: запись `E1[E2]` идентична записи `(*((E1)+(E2)))`*» — ISO/IEC 9899:2011 раздел 6.5.2.1 (примечание переводчика).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос страдает от странной формулировки. "Имя массива"? Что значит "имя массива"?

1. *Имя* в терминологии С - это просто идентификатор. *Имя массива* - это просто *имя массива* и больше ничего. Оно больше ничем не является и являться не может.
2. *Объект* типа *массив* в языке С не является указателем. Тип `T[N]` в языке С - это самостоятельный объектный тип, описывающий монолитный непрерывный объект, состоящий из `N` следующих друг за другом подобъектов (элементов) типа `T`. Гарантируется , что `sizeof(T[N])` равен `sizeof(T) * N`.

   Никаких "указателей" здесь нет и никогда не было.
3. Подвыражение, состоящее из имени (идентификатора) объекта типа *массив* `T[N]` может *неявно преобразовываться* к типу *указатель* `T *`. Будет или не будет выполняться такое преобразование, зависит от контекста.

   А именно, если такое подвыражение используется в качестве операнда операторов `&`, `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, то преобразования НЕ выполняется. Также, если строковый литерал используется в качестве инициализатора для массива символов, то преобразования строкового литерала к типу *указатель* НЕ выполняется. Во всех остальных случаях преобразование выполняется: значение типа *массив* неявно преобразуется к типу *указатель*.

Comment: Один автор пишет: Мы можем, например, установить указатель p таким образом, чтобы он указывал на один из элементов массива a. Для первого элемента это будет выглядеть так: p = &a[0]; Вы в свою очередь пишите: "если такое подвыражение используется в качестве операнда операторов &, sizeof, _Alignof, то преобразования НЕ выполняется". Кто из вас прав?

Answer (score 1):

Массив имеет разный размер в памяти а адрес фиксированный. В массиве автоматически идёт преобразование типа на адрес, если надо. Копировать массив прямо на другой - не прописано в стандарте.

```
# include <stdio.h>
// аргумент принимает адрес инта или адрес массива
void m(int * x) {
  x[0] = 777 ; }
// аргумент принимает адрес инта или адрес массива любого
void f(int x[5]) {
  x[0] = 777 ; }

typedef  
struct {
  int a[5];
} int5 ;  

void f2(int5 x) {
  x.a[0] = 777 ; }

int5 n(void) {
  int5 r;
  r.a[1] = 666 ;
  return r; }

int main(){
  // внутри стека выделяется 5*4=20 байт
  int a[5];
  a[0] = 0 ;
  // передаётся адрес стека 8 байт
  m(a);
  printf("m:a[0]=%d\n",a[0]);
  a[0]=0;
  // тоже только адрес стека 8 байт
  f(a);
  printf("f:a[0]=%d\n",a[0]);
  int a4 = 0;
  f ( & a4 ) ;
  printf("f:a4=%d\n",a4);
  int a2[5];
  // ошибка присвоения указателя массиву
  // a2 = a ;
  int * a3 ;
  // указателю назначается адрес стека
  a3 = a ;
  int5 b ;
  b.a[0]=0;
  // передается копия структуры и копия массива внутри её
  f2(b);
  printf("f2:b.a[0]=%d\n",b.a[0]);
  b.a[1]=0;
  // полное копирование массива внутри структуры
  b = n();
  printf("n:b.a[1]=%d\n",b.a[1]);
}
```

Зато копировать структуру можно. Даже если там массив. При передачи массива внутри структуры всё идёт как надо. Передача по значению присутствует. Оператор присваивания копирует данные.

```
> ./a.out 
m:a[0]=777
f:a[0]=777
f:a4=777
f2:b.a[0]=0
n:b.a[1]=666
```

Массив при передаче прямо работает как указатель. А как источник данных внутри структуры как положено полностью со всеми данными.

Comment: Что значит «массив имеет разный размер в памяти»?

Comment: @eanmos Если 20 элементов или десять в разных участках программы объём стека уменьшается на разное количество байт.