# Как в одной и той же ячейке памяти могут лежать 2 значения?

Tags: c

Если есть массив `int Array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 }`, то его адрес будет `&Array` (к примеру `0xFFF`), если разыменовать его: `*(&Array)` это аналогично `Array`, то получим то же адрес (`0xFFF`), то есть получается, что в ячейке по адресу `0xFFF` лежит значение `0xFFF`, но если разыменовать `*Array`, то по адресу `0xFFF` лежит значение `1`. Как в одной и той же ячейке памяти могут лежать 2 значения? Или массив реализован через union?

Comment: Какие два значения? Похоже, вы как-то неверно представляете себе, что такое массив... Гляньте сюда - https://ideone.com/D2fsB0 - может, это прояснит ситуацию?

Comment: Массив — это **не** указатель. Но в некоторых ситуациях происходит неявное приведение массива к указателю на его первый элемент. Вы совсем недавно задавали подобный вопрос. В комментариях я оставлял ссылку на вопрос [Имя массива — это указатель?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1005812) Вы с ним ознакомились?

Comment: @Harry, &Array == Array, но *(&Array) != *Array - один адрес, значения разные.

Comment: `*Array` - это не адрес, это значение первого элемента массива...

Comment: Я про то, что например &Array == Array == 0xBLA-BLA-BLA, то есть адреса одинаковые, тогда если разыменовать адрес - получу значение ячейки памяти по этому адресу, тогда если оба выражения имеют один и тот же адрес, то первый *(&Array) выведет 0xBLA-BLA-BLA, а второй *Array - значение первого элемента  массива.

Comment: Адрес один, а значение в ячейке по адресу разные.

Comment: Здесь `*(&Array)` вы получаете **массив**. Когда вы его пытаетесь вывести, массив **неявно преобразуется** к указателю на свой первый элемент, поэтому выводится **адрес** (но не значение по этому адресу!). Здесь `*Array` вы применяете оператор разыменования к **массиву**, и он (массив) снова неявно преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент. Разыменовывая указатель на первый элемент массива вы получаете **значение** первого элемента массива.

Comment: @wololo, я понимаю, но массив это же просто абстракция, если просто забыть про массив, а думать про ячейки памяти и их адреса. Когда разыменовать массив, то получим адрес первого элемента? Получается, что С обманывает нас? Меня в первую очередь волнует, что адреса одинаковые, то есть есть ячейка памяти, пусть и из виртуального пространства, то в ячейке должно что-то быть, если разыменовать ее, но разыменовуя одну и ту же ячейку - результаты разные.

Comment: Вы то можете забыть о массиве, а компилятор - нет.

Comment: `но разыменовуя одну и ту же ячейку - результаты разные` ну так и указатели, которые указывают на одну и туже ячейку памяти интерпретируют её **по разному**! `&Array[0]` — это указатель на целое число — `int*`, а `&Array` — это указатель на весь массив, в данном случае, указатель на 3 целых числа — `int(*)[3]`. Вас не удивляет, что  значение `*(float*)(&Array[0])` будет отличаться от `*(&Array[0])`? Разыменовали одну и ту же ячейку, а результаты разные.

Comment: @wololo, согласен, просто тогда те 4 байта будут рассмотрены как число с плавающей запятой IEEE-754, но двоичное значение все-равно то, что и было, интерпретация разная, но в моем случае, если первым элементом будет число 1 массива int, то в памяти это в hex 01 00 00 00 если рассматривать little endian, так как оно и есть, тогда будет *Array на выводе 1, но *(&Array) не будет 0x00000001, хотя в памяти лежит 1, но выведет адрес.

Comment: Как я понимаю, С автоматически делает какие-то манипуляции, что бы упростить жизнь программиста, но при этом немного ломает логику.

Comment: `*(&Array) не будет 0x00000001`, да, потому что `*(&Array)` — это не `int`, чтобы его вывести как целое число, и не `float`, чтобы вывести его как число с плавающей точкой, `*(&Array)` — это **массив**. Как вы предлагаете выводить массив? Хотите вывести первый элемент? А почему не все элементы сразу? Или почему бы не вывести _адрес_?

Comment: Как вы вообще пытаетесь вывести `*(&Array)`? Наверное, как-то так: `printf("%d", *(&Array))`? Так вот, при передаче массива в функцию, массив преобразуется к указателю на свой первый элемент. Это особенность синтаксиса.

Answer (score 2):

Есть массив `int Array[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };`. Он имеет тип `int [3]`.

Адрес массива `int (*Arrayp)[3] = & Array;` имеет тип `int(*)[3]`.

При выводе на консоль массива выводиться только его адрес `int(*)[3]`. А если вы хотите вывести на консоль адрес массива, то выводиться тоже адрес `int(*)[3]`.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте попробуем *упрощенно* представить себе, что же такое массив...

```
int a;
```

Тут все понятно - есть переменная, т.е. место в памяти, куда можно что-то записать, и поэтому имеет смысл запись `a = 2;`, например.

```
int * a;
```

Тоже понятно. Есть переменная - место в памяти, в которой хранится адрес другого места в памяти. Если все значения верны - имеет смысл как присвоение `a = p;`, т.е. в переменной теперь новый адрес, так и `*a = 5;` - запись по адресу, хранящемуся в переменной, и даже `&a` - получение места в памяти, в котором хранится адрес другого места в памяти, в котором...

```
int a[5]
```

Тут все сложнее потому, что это - *статически* выделенная память, которая имеет все время своего существования одно и то же местоположение. Известное компилятору, и неизменное. Так что запись `a = ...` лишена смысла, ибо `a` - не указатель, а по сути псевдоним некоторого адреса. Как если бы в примерах выше `a` была не переменной типа `int`, а конкретной двойкой - ведь что присваивание `2 = 3;`, что взятие адреса `&2` - бессмысленны.

Но поскольку `a` уже само по себе неизменный псевдоним неизменного адреса, то его можно рассматривать и как адрес места в памяти, где лежат эти 5 `int`'ов. И для упрощения жизни - как, например, с функцией, для которой `*f` является той же функцией, операция получения адреса массива возвращает этот неизменный адрес, в который превращается имя самого массива (которое и есть адрес).

Ну вот как-то так - не совсем строго, упрощенно - но, может, так понятнее? *"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Надеюсь, я нигде не перешел границы дозволенного стандартом? :)